# Cannot connect to my WiFi: "Saved, secured with WPA /WPA2"

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, connection-issues

I cannot connect to my WiFi at all. I have a Nexus 5 and it has been fine for a long time. All of a sudden, I just cannot connect to my WiFi. I try to connect, and it either says that I am out of range, or that my connection is secure. When I enter my passcode, it just doesn't connect, gives no error or anything. It just keeps saying secure connection. I am on KitKat, the latest version.

Comment: How far are you from your wifi router?

Comment: Next to it really.

Comment: Does this happens to other devices who are connected to your router?
And does it happens to your device when you are on another wifi router?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an Android issue, so much as a WiFi problem. A while ago (before I got my Android) I had some issues connecting my computer to my WiFi -- my computer sensed that the network was there, but wouldn't connect. I was advised to reset the network.

- Unplug all parts of the network: router, modem etc.
- Hold your breath for ten seconds.
- Reconnect everything.
- Try connecting to your network again.

This worked for my computer; give it a try for your phone, and tell us what happens.

Comment: I give my neighbors guest access to my personal router. They have Android Fire HD and another generic tablet. Their connection goes out periodically (work outside on the lines did it once). My home network (iPhone, Macbook Air, Lenovo/Arch) will be fine, but their units continue to attempt to connect. Restarting the router did the trick. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I get this very regularly, and the problem is usually down to the router but occasionally the Nexus.

- In WiFi settings, "Forget" the connection details.
- Reboot the router and phone.
- Once available, connect to the network again and re-enter your details.

On my Nexus 7, entering a static IP fixed the problem when I was at the edge of WiFi range, but as you say you're near the router this wouldn't seem to be the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens if you aren't near the router or have put an incorrect password...